# Tricky logarithm problem

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

I having a problem in this logarithm problem involving modulus-
Solve for x

|x-1|^((log(x))^2-2log(x))=|x-1|^3

Bases same so powers equal.

If I take log x as a then I get the following quadratic-
A^2-2a-3=0

So x values are 1000 and 0.1. Which is correct. Now there is one more solution to the question which is x=2.

When I subsitute 2 then obviously it is satisfying the equation. But how do we derive it ? Pls help

Comment: $1^a = 1^b$ for all $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$. Thus "Bases same so powers equal" does not hold for all bases.

Comment: $|x-1|=1 \implies x=2 \vee x=0$. Obviously the equation is not defined for $x=0$ due to the $log(x)$, hence you're left with $x=2$.

Comment: @barakmanos Why did you equate |x-1| to 1. How did the 1 come?

Comment: @DanielFischer but in this case the first part of my question is right, right?

Comment: See one comment above mine.

Comment: The case for $\lvert x-1\rvert \neq 1$ is correct.

Comment: How does it strike someone that is 1 that it is to be equated? I am sorry but I can't understand it fully.

Comment: To emphasize @DanielFischer's first comment, $\forall{a,b}\in\mathbb{R}:1^a=1^b$.

Comment: By the way, in addition to that, $\forall{a,b\neq0}\in\mathbb{R}:0^a=0^b$.

Comment: Is there a better method to go about solving this so as to get all three ans like by making a cubic or something or removing the mod sign?

Comment: What mod sign?????

Comment: Absolute value sign

Comment: So |x-1|=0 so x=1 also an answer? @barakmanos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution to the equation $|x-1|^{log(x)^2-2log(x)}=|x-1|^3$:

- $log(x)^2-2log(x)=3$
- $|x-1|=1$
- $[|x-1|=0]\wedge[log(x)^2-2log(x)\neq0]$

Pitfalls to watch for:

- Make sure that the solution doesn't yield $0^0$
- Make sure that the solution doesn't yield $log(0)$

Comment: thanks a lot....understood.

Comment: @user166748: You're welcome :)